# Really need this for loop?

Tags: java, loops

I have this code when the user enters a code for a color it's supposed to give the user the color name like for example "A01" it would then say "Red" then display the color but how do I get the loop to go through the array? Here's the whole code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayColor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String d="A01"; 
    String h="A01"; 
    String colorCode[] [] = { {"A01","Red"}, {"B07","Blue"}, {"H02", "Yellow"},{"M04", "Orange"}, {"O05","Black"}, {"L08", "While"} }; 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    d = getColor();
    for(int i=0; i<colorCode.length -1; i++){
        System.out.println(colorCode[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace your 2D array with a [`java.util.HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> colorCode = new HashMap<String, String>();
colorCode.put("A01","Red");
colorCode.put("B07","Blue");
colorCode.put("H02", "Yellow")
/* .. etc... */
```

Then you can retrieve the color by doing something like (without a `for` loop):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
String color = colorCode.get(userInput);
System.out.println(color);
```

Of course, you should check if `userInput` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for(int i=0; i<colorCode.length -1; i++)
```

With:

```
for(int i=0; i<colorCode.length; i++)
```

Lets say `colorCode.length` is equal to 1 (there is one element in the array). If you are iterating while `i` is less than `colorCode.length - 1`, which is equal to 0, your code will not run, because 0 is not less than 0.